# Problems to solve using control instructions in C for practice

Tags: c, loops, logic

Need some good problems which students can think of and apply their own logic to solve them using **control instructions** only. The topics covered until now are basic, not even arrays are done yet. But, I want students to be perfect before proceeding to higher topics.

I tried searching for some example problems, none were as I expected / they were the ones which I already knew.

Some of which I know:

1. Write a program to find out the value of a^b without using built in functions.
2. Write a program to find out Armstrong numbers between a range.
3. Write a program to print binary equivalent of a number in reverse order (since arrays are not yet done, just simple logic to print the remainder and divide the number further)
4. Count all -ve, +ve and 0 numbers entered by user until user wishes to terminate the program.
5. Write a program to display all divisors of a given number.
6. Write a program to find if the given number is prime or not.
7. Check if the given number is odd or even.

Need more good logically interesting problems which would help students to build their problem solving capability.

Thanks.

PS: Please forgive me if this question is vague or not to the point coz this question has scope for vast answers and I cannot accept a single answer, I guess?

Comment: 1.Write a program to find out the value of a^b without using built in functions. Hope your students are only students otherwise you can see some one answering int main(){int a=8;b=10; return a^b;} ;)

Comment: By "^" I mean the power function.

Answer (score 1):

```
Print first 33 terms of Fibonacci-Series

Write factorial of n being input from keyboard on console.

Find hours,minutes,seconds from given seconds.(305 s = 5m + 5s ....)

Calculate dot-product and cross-product of two 2D vectors.

Find the intersecting point of two lines(m=slope, (x0,y0)=a point for each line)

Calculate sin(pi/4) with using series expansion

Print the minimum of values given from keyboard on screen.

Simulate **and** , **or** and **xor** gates.

Find projection of a vector(3D) on another vector. 

Find area of a polygon(2D)

Calculate the integral of x-square between x=0 and x=3 using integration by trapezoidal rule


Find roots of: (x-square) plus (two times x) plus (one) equals (zero)
```

Comment: Thanks for lovely ideas, also any way of achieving dot and cross product of 2D vectors without using Data structures? Coz Arrays have not yet been covered for students. Also could you kindly explain: 1. Area of polygon 2. Integral of x-squre? I think these have got integration involved, isnt it? Thanks.

Comment: just separate variables for like x1,y1 for vector1 and x2,y2 for vector 2.

Comment: there are many integration techniques. I mentioned trapezoidal rule. For the area of a polygon, the only i didnt tried :D

Answer (score 1):

- Check if number is a palindrome (1234554321)
- Rewrite a function using write() to print a number in the console (similar to `printf("%d", ...)`)
- A function that writes all combinations of 2 digits starting from 12 to 89, not allowing twice the same digit, nor a different order (`12, 13, ..., 19, 23, 24...` : skipping 21 because it's done with 12)
- A function that write all combinations of n digits (n given as a parameter from 1 to 9) with the same rules (without using arrays)

Comment: Great thanks! But what exactly is your second point about? Rewrite a function using write() to print a number in console - how do we do it?

Comment: Decompose the number in digits, and print them in the right order. Can be done recursively easily or iteratively.

Comment: using modulo, division, and carrying the correct part over to the next iteration.
A simple exercise but useful to train for a real beginner

Comment: Decomposing is the same as that of palindrome of a number. But I was wondering that the whole number could also be printed using write function too just as printf(). Then why write() function in particular?

Comment: No, `write` function writes chars from the memory to the terminal, you can't write a whole int with just one call to `write`. Then `write` in particular because it is the closest thing they have to "Write this char to the terminal" without going down to asm levels.